# How to set Jbuttons to a specific place when you have a background in JLabel : code below

Tags: java, swing, background-image, jbutton, jlabel

How to set Jbuttons to a specific place when you have a background in JLabel : code below
i can't get the jlabel to stay at the top and the buttons to stay south(bottom) ??

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonsClass extends JFrame
              implements ActionListener {
    JButton b1 = new JButton("button1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("button2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("button3");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("button4");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("buttons:");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ButtonsClass();
}

public Jukebox() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.png")));
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(500,150);
    setTitle("Backgroundwithbuttons");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);


   JPanel top = new JPanel();

    top.add(label);
    add("North", top);
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.add(b1); 
    bottom.add(b2); 
    bottom.add(b3); 
    bottom.add(b4); 
    add("South", bottom); 
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " i can't get the jlabel to stay at the top and the buttons to stay south(bottom)"

- That's because you set the layout the `BorderLayout`, then immediately set it to `FlowLayout`. With `FlowLayout`, your `BorderLayout` positioning will do *nothing*.

  ```
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.png")));
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  ```

Just get rid of the `setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

- Also your constructor is wrong

  ```
  public Jukebox() {

  -Should be- 

  public ButtonClass() {
  ```
- Also you need to set the layout of the `JLabel` that you set as the content pane. Yout constructor should look like this

  ```
  public ButtonClass() {
      JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.png"));
      background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setContentPane(background);
      setTitle("Background with buttons");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel top = new JPanel();
      top.add(label);
      add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
      bottom.add(b1);
      bottom.add(b2);
      bottom.add(b3);
      bottom.add(b4);
      add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      //pack();
      setVisible(true);
  }
  ```
- Also, `add("North", top);` is a deprecated method. Instead use `add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH)` and same for `add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH)`
- Also, Swing apps should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread. You can do so by wrapping the code in your `main` with a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater...`

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              new ButtonClass();
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- Also, you should set the panel's opaque property to false, if you want the image to show behind them.

  ```
  top.setOpaque(false);
  bottom.setOpaque(false);
  ```

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonClass extends JFrame
        implements ActionListener {

    JButton b1 = new JButton("button1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("button2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("button3");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("button4");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("buttons:");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ButtonClass();
            }
        });
    }

    public ButtonClass() {
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/space.png")));
        background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(background);
        setTitle("Background with buttons");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.setOpaque(false);
        top.add(label);
        add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setOpaque(false);
        bottom.add(b1);
        bottom.add(b2);
        bottom.add(b3);
        bottom.add(b4);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
 at ButtonClass.<init>(ButtonClass.java:24)
 at ButtonClass$1.run(ButtonClass.java:12                        i got this exception i dont know why

Comment: You need to change the image path to yours

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

instead of:

add("South", bottom);

[BorderLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Comment: It didn't work it came out with the same thing as before they are all on the top bit